# Magento category URL empty in backend

Tags: category, url, indexing

Our category URL in the backend is empty. But our sites work fine with the value that was there before. If I create a new category then I do see the URL key value. What can be causing this?

```
New category=URL key
Old category=no URL key empty
```

We investigated `catalog_category_entity_varchar` and saw that many category values were duplicated on a lower (store hierarchy) level. Strange.

Help or clues appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what happened without seeing code or poking through the db, but...
it may work because the urls come from the `core_url_rewrites` table.
You might still have values for the categories in there.
But you still need to investigate what happened to the url keys.
Maybe the db is corrupted.
Check if you have values in the `catalog_category_entity_vacrchar` for the `url_key` attribute.

You can get the id of the attribute like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM eav_attribute
WHERE attribute_code = 'url_key' AND
    entity_type_id = (SELECT 
                          entity_type_id 
                      FROM 
                          eav_entity_type
                      WHERE
                          entity_type_code = 'catalog_category')
```

Then get the id from the query above and run

```
SELECT * from catalog_category_entity_varchar where attribute_id = ID_FROM_QUERY_ABOVE
```

There is also the possibility that you still have values for the url keys at store view level, but you are missing the ones for the default values scope.
This way the website can function without any issues, but it creates confusion for the admins.

Comment: hmmmmm first query: url_key return no result (for a know URL key that works) ....

Comment: So, something happened to your db. Sorry, but I cannot guess what. Get a backup from a few days ago and compare the values (if you have a backup)

Comment: you are doing the query wrong. There is not attribute id `catalog/product_attribute_backend_urlkey`. You have to get the actuall id. you took the backend model

Comment: Thanks Marius. It took some time to understand what I was doing. But actually your 'steps' are exactly what solved it. I solved it by getting backup from some days back and compare it to production. All values seem to have duplicates on a lower hierarchy level and all default config (scope 0) values were NULLED. Very strange. But solved through bacjup restore. MANY THANKS!!!